# Collection<KProperty1<I,*>> How to get the property instance

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently using Reflection to inspect an element at runtime using the `class.memberProperties` function. The type of `properties` is `collection<KProperty1<I, *>>` so I run through each of the `KProperty` objects to find the one that I want by checking if the name is equal to "nameIWant", though I would much rather be able to get the instance of the property from the `KProperty` by using the `.get()` method on the `property`, so that then I could do a check such as:

```
if (property.get(receiver) is ClassIWant) {
  //Do something
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
val properties = request.payload::class.memberProperties
  properties.forEach { property ->
    run {
      if (property.name.equals("nameIWant")) {

      }
    }
  }
```

So far I've been trying to use the `.get()` method on the `KProperty1` type but it takes an argument `receiver` of type `Nothing`. I'm not able to work out what I need to pass in order to call the `.get()` method and get the particular instance of the property. I've also checked the documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/index.html but it hasn't really helped at all.

Comment: can you show the code that you use to get the value via `property.get(receiver)`? It should work, if you pass an actual instance of your payload request.

Comment: The property.get(receiver) code doesn't compile because the receiver type is expected to be Nothing? Passing in the payload request has a type of I.

Comment: nice that you see that compiler error, but I don't and I can't reproduce it. Can you please share your code?

Comment: how do you get your receiver? why is your collection generic type `KProperty1<I` and not `KProperty1<Payload`? I am looking for that missing piece of information...

Comment: Actually the `payload` has type `I`, so the type of `properties` is `Collection<KProperty1<I, *>>`, in the collection they can be different types. For example, the first and second `KProperty`s are Strings and the third is another object type MyObject. What I was hoping for was to be able to do ```val obj : MyObj = property.get({What to put here, requires type Nothing})```, so that later I can do ```obj.id = "1234"```, since only the MyObject object has the field id, not the two Strings.

Comment: I mean... how can it have type `I`? where does this come from? On any example I construct I am able to extract the values... even on a very generic variant... so there must still be something missing... I assume `request` is an object with a property named `payload` which is a generic type, is that correct?

Comment: Yes `request` is an object with a property named `payload`. The I is a generic that implements another class we have `Foo`. So the function declaration is like so: `fun <I:Foo> create(request: DRequest<I>, responseClass: KClass<I>) : DResponse<I> {`

Comment: still... even if I construct something like that, it works for me... I assume you have some sort of problem with your generic type information so you end up with `Nothing` instead of `Foo` or a deviation/implementation of it...

Comment: @Programming123 it seems that in your code `property` has type `KProperty1<out I, *>`. You can try to explicitly cast it to `KProperty1<I, *>` and then you can use `property.get(request.payload)`

Comment: @AndreiTanana Thanks so much Andrei, you were right it had a type of `KProperty1<out I, *>` which needed to be explicitly cast to `KProperty1<I, *>`, I'm not sure why this happened or what the `out I` means but glad it sorted now :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the value of the property, cast the class into invariant type.

```
instance::class.memberProperties.first() // returns KProperty1<out Instance, *>
(instance::class as KClass<Instance>).memberProperties.first() // returns KProperty1<Instance, *>
```

If your `KClass<Instance>` is `KClass<*>`, use `Any` as `Instance`.

Why did the `KProperty.call` take `Nothing` as receiver?
Because `instance::class` returns `KClass<out Instance>`, which propagates the covariant type argument down to the property, which it becomes `KProperty<out Instance, *>`, which narrows down the possible method receiver to any subtype of Instance, but because we do not know which, we can not safely supply any instance of Instance, as show by the rules of variance, which here limit the generic type argument to `Nothing`, which means it is impossible to call the method at all.

Why is `::class` designed to be covariant?
To guarantee safety. This has been an issue of great debates as it seems somewhat illogical.

If you want to know the type of the value that the property can return, use

```
property.returnType
```

It returns a KType, wich is Kotlin's version of Java's Type, which is a more generic concept of a Class (which is one of the implementations of Type).

If you need to 'convert' the KType to a KClass, you need to do the same as if you needed to convert Type to a Class, which is get the raw type of the type. Raw type is type stripped of the any generic information, yes, an erased type. The way to do this is (seemingly) more complicated (involves handling each possible KType/Type implementation) and I recommend checking for answer to this problem separately.

You will be able to reuse Java implementation (that you will surely find on your own) using:

```
kType.javaType.covertJavaTypeToJavaClass().kotlin  // returns KClass<*>
```

Corrections in your question. I recommend using the proper terms if you wish to receive proper answers:
* `I` in your question is type of the method receiver, not the value of the property
* `collection` is not a type, `Collection is`
* `property is ClassIWant`is ambiguous as `property.type` is type of the value in the property and `property::class` is simply the property implementation, `is` is also an `instanceof` check, but in reflection, you need to use `KClass.isSubclassOf`, or what is known in Java as `type.isAssignableFrom` (watch the call order), which then makes your condition to be `ClassIWant.isSuperclassOf(property.type.getRawType())`
* `instance of the property` properties have values, not instances. Only classes have instances. Instances are values and values are instances (of some class), but you must still say `instance representing the value of the property`

Answer (score 3):

justPassingBy is right. but the more simple way is to use:

```
myObj.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.foreach { property ->
      property.get(myObj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prop.getter.call(obj) as String?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `KType` for your `ClassIWant` and then check the property's `returnType`. It will be something like this:

```
val properties = request.payload::class.memberProperties
val desiredType = ClassIWant::class.createType()
properties.forEach { property ->
    if (property.name == "nameIWant" && property.returnType == desiredType) {
        //todo
    }
}
```

btw you can cast your property variable to correct type and use `get`

```
val properties = request.payload::class.memberProperties
properties.forEach { property ->
    val value = (property as KProperty1<Payload, *>).get(request.payload)
    if (property.name == "nameIWant" && value is ClassIWant) {
        //todo
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. The issue is that the `property` variable is a `KProperty1` type and not the type that I want to perform operations on, such as String. I'm trying to understand how to use the .get(receiver) function, are you familiar with it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your problem. I know that `property` has type `KProperty1<out Payload, *>`. That's why I'm using `returnType`